# How to remove changes related to one file from patch

Tags: git, git-patch

I've got a patch created with `git format-patch` and when trying to apply it to `master` I faced that some file changes are now obsolete and there's no reason to apply them. Example:

```
git apply 00001-my.patch
error: patch failed: my_file.c:68
error: my_file.c: patch does not apply
```

Is there some command to reformat the patch file to completely remove all changes related to the file `my_file.c`?